# Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning Occured

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, es6-promise

I want to create Product Categories , so i handle it in `productController` class database call in `productCatService` class. I added JS promise to this . now it gives following error.

**productCatController.js**

```
module.exports.createProductCat = async (request, response)=> {
 

        let result = await productCatService.createProductCat(productCatData);
      

        if (result) {
            responseService.successWithData(response, "Product Category Created");
        } else {
            responseService.errorWithMessage(response, result);
        }
   

}
```

**productCatService.js**

```
module.exports.createProductCat = (productCatData) => {


    let productCat = {
        name: productCatData.name,
        desc: productCatData.desc,
        count:productCatData.count,
        status : productCatData.status
    };


    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        ProductCategory.create(productCat).then(result => {
           resolve(true);
        }).catch(error => {
          reject(false)
        })
    });


}
```

**Error**

```
(node:18808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: false
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:18808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a p
romise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.
html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:18808) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a no
n-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `await` without `try`/`catch`. You don't have to `try`/`catch` *every* `await`, but somewhere down the call stack there needs to be a `try`/`catch` block.

You don't need `try`/`catch` here, just return the promise from `ProductCategory.create()`...

```
// productCatService.js
module.exports.createProductCat = (productCatData) => ProductCategory.create({
    name: productCatData.name,
    desc: productCatData.desc,
    count: productCatData.count,
    status: productCatData.status
});
```

...but you *definitely* need `try`/`catch` here, as this function is the bottom of the stack for this operation, and it is responsible for signifying overall success or failure to the caller.

```
// productCatController.js
module.exports.createProductCat = async (request, response) => {
    try {
        await productCatService.createProductCat(productCatData);
        responseService.successWithData(response, "Product Category Created");
    } catch (err) {
        responseService.errorWithMessage(response, err);
    }
}
```

Also [don't use `new Promise()` for operations that *already are* promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/). Keep using the promise you already have. Wrapping `new Promise()` around existing promises is a source of useless bloat, and it can introduce subtle bugs. Avoid.

Comment: Awesome Explanation ! Thanks . sequelize gives us to handle result using `then()` `catch()`  , can't we use those options instead of `try` `catch` https://snipboard.io/1yxfKQ.jpg

Comment: @Sameera `something().then(result => use(result)).catch(err => show(err));` and `try { var result = await something(); use(result); } catch (err) { show(err); }` are exactly the same thing.

Comment: ...when you think about that for a moment, you'll see that that means you can absolutely use `await` and `try`/`catch` with sequelize.

Comment: (but you don't have to. Use `.then()` / `.catch()` if you like that better.)

Comment: Thanks Tom ! I fixed it . Thanks again for saving my time .